# Is it possible to define a Web Api Route which accepts a literal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

I defined a route for the Web Api as follows

```
 routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "SearchApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/search/{controller}-{seopath}",
                defaults: new { seopath = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

However, when I run it from visual studio and go to http://localhost:50356/api/search/jobs-in-Bangalore I get 404 error with the message "No type was found that matches the controller named 'jobs-in'."

In the book, Professional Asp.Net MVC 1.0, pg 207 {title}-{author} is given as a valid route url, so why is it interpreting "jobs-in" as a controller instead of "jobs" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the match is greedy.  Why not define your route like:

```
routeTemplate: "api/search/{controller}/{seopath}"
```

Comment: well, we had a hacky way in the old webforms website where url's such as "site.com/jobs-in-bangalore" were mapped to a a particular page with certain query string parameters. e.g. "jobs-in-bangalore" would map to "search.aspx?City=Bangalore" These urls are present in search engine results so it would be great to just support the format. But it seems that cannot be possible in any way?

Comment: If you want to maintain your existing SEO URIs, you can write a custom route contstraint (see http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx for examples) or you could utilize IIS' URL Rewrite (http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).  Personally, I would go with the custom constraint.